# FlutterJNI.loadLibrary called more than once (FlutterJNI.prefetchDefaultFontManager, FlutterJNI.init)

Tags: flutter

after updating Android Studio and flutter (and kotlin) i get this warnings/errors

how to solve or can i ignore without consequential error?

Thank you in anvance.

```
W/FlutterJNI(23046): FlutterJNI.loadLibrary called more than once
W/FlutterJNI(23046): FlutterJNI.prefetchDefaultFontManager called more than once
W/FlutterJNI(23046): FlutterJNI.init called more than once
```

Edit 23.03.2022:

it's because "await Firebase.initializeApp();" is called twice like in the documentation mentioned. i have to research more. maybe solution with firebase_options.dart.

[image]

Edit 16.04.2022:

```
Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp(options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,);
}

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,);

  // Set the background messaging handler early on, as a named top-level function
  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);

  //String? token =
  await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getAPNSToken();
  await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getToken();
  //print('APNS token: $token');
}
```

Comment: I had the same issue when I was trying some stuff out with firebase messaging. Unfortunately I couldnt find a fix and went back to flutter 2.8.1 :/

Comment: if i remove all firebase lines from source code, the error is gone.
i tried older versions of both plugins without success (firebase_messaging, firebase_core).

Comment: the creation of the firebase_options.dart file didn't help. still the same error.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70404936/missing-firebase-options-dart-file-in-course-get-to-know-firebase-for-flutter

Comment: This message doesn't seem to cause any problem in the app.

Comment: Hi, @AlexF1 do you found the solution for your issue? coz I'm facing the same like yours. mind to share your solution if you already solved it. Thanks.

Comment: I didn't find a solution. This App project is canceled so I'm not looking for a solution anymore.

Answer (score 11):

I was facing the same error. This message shows if you call `FirebaseMessaging.instance` multiple times. For Example:

```
    final _firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance
    await _firebaseMessaging.requestPermission(
      announcement: true,
      carPlay: true,
      criticalAlert: true,
    );
    await 
FirebaseMessaging.instance.setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions(
      alert: true,
      badge: true,
      sound: true,
    );
```

So here, the `FirebaseMessaging.instance` is called twice.  Solved by changing `FirebaseMessaging.instance` to `_firebaseMessaging`. Hope this might help.

Note: Do not use `FirebaseMessaging.instance` in differenta files, or use it by passing the initialized one.

Comment: i dont have this case. just the one from the question like the plugin said in example

https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging/example

Comment: Can you provide the code snippit or github repo link!

Comment: I added it to the question above.

Comment: I highly doubt that having FirebaseMessaging.instance at more than one place is the issue. The one thing that is forbidden is to be called twice is Firebase.initializeAp(). Even in firebase_messaging official example, they have FirebaseMessaging.instance in more than one place. From my understanding, instance returns the global/singleton of our app's firebaseMessaging; so go ahead and call it many times. Please look at https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging/example