# I am trying to implement firebase messaging in my flutter app, and it is showing 'FlutterJNI.loadLibrary called more than once'. What should I do?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging

Here is my code -

```
@pragma('vm:entry-point')
Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(_) async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
}

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  await FirebaseAppCheck.instance.activate(
    androidProvider: AndroidProvider.playIntegrity,
  );
  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);
  await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
      .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
          AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
      ?.createNotificationChannel(channel);
  await FirebaseMessaging.instance.setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions(
    alert: true,
    badge: true,
    sound: true,
  );
  runApp(
    MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(
          create: (_) => MainProvider(),
        ),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(
          create: (_) => SellerFormProvider(),
        ),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(
          create: (_) => LocationProvider(),
        ),
      ],
      child: const MyApp(),
    ),
  );
  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
    DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
    DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
  ]);
}
```

And here is the console log errors -

```
W/FlutterJNI(32413): FlutterJNI.loadLibrary called more than once
W/FlutterJNI(32413): FlutterJNI.prefetchDefaultFontManager called more than once
I/ResourceExtractor(32413): Found extracted resources res_timestamp-6-1669032211535
W/FlutterJNI(32413): FlutterJNI.init called more than once
I/FLTFireBGExecutor(32413): Creating background FlutterEngine instance.
W/DartExecutor(32413): Attempted to run a DartExecutor that is already running.
```

Please help me with this issue. I think the error is occuring because we are calling Firebase.initializeApp() twice in the code.
But I am not able to understand how to remove the error.

Comment: Do check out https://stackoverflow.com/q/71514802/11212287

Comment: I already checked this, it doesn't solves the issue.

Comment: Try removing `FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler)` , `flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin`  and `FirebaseMessaging.instance` methods from the `main()` method. 

Add those to the SplashScreen or your app's entry point

Comment: There is no separate splash screen file as I used a package for that. And I am already implementing it in the entry point of my app which is the main() method right?

Comment: By entry point I meant the first widget of the app. Try adding it in the initState of the first screen.