# Trying to run app on flutter web throws exception [Error: Assertion failed:]

Tags: flutter, firebase, flutter-web

Today I was trying to run my app to see if it works on the WEB and when I run it, I get this exception and a blank google chrome page. I think it has to do with firebase. Do you have any ideas on solving this?

[image]

Comment: Is your firebase configuration correct (eg: "await Firebase.initializeApp(options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);")?

Comment: I had mine just like this await Firebase.initializeApp(), without the options. I tried adding the options now but I get "Undefined name 'DefaultFirebaseOptions'." From what library is defaultfirebaseoptions?

Comment: You should check the firebase documentation according to the version in your `pubspec.yaml`. Most probably you will have to create a new web app in your firebase console and add it's configuration in the `web/index.html` in your project if you are on an older version of firebase

Comment: Yep, it works, i checked this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70404936/missing-firebase-options-dart-file-in-course-get-to-know-firebase-for-flutter